# car not starting after few km

Tags: battery, troubleshooting

In the morning my car starts in a single quick shot. After traveling for few KMs if I switch off car and try to start it, it does not come up. I can hear a small tick sound every time. Some times I can hear the small attempt of rolling starter. Then I wait for a couple of minutes, precisely for 4-5 minutes, and the car starts like normal.

Car is not over heating ..... 
starter motor has been recently serviced just to make sure.

I have added battery water till top level indicator.

I feel it is a battery issue. Should I go for a new battery or is it something to do with low acidic level in battery?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the ability to do so, I would get the battery checked. This seems to me to be the likely cause of your issue. A parts store should be able to check it for you. It sounds as though there is what is called a "surface charge". This condition usually stems from having a weak cell or two in the battery.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the starter motor isn't getting enough power, and you've just had work done on it.

Check all the wires between the battery and the starter motor for a loose connection.

Or as Paulster2 said you might just need to buy a new battery.

Answer (score 0):

I'll pipe in and suggest that the issue may be your alternator. Your battery is typically used to start the car, after which the alternator kicks in to provide your car's electrical needs and re-charge your battery. When the alternator goes bad, you drain your battery as you drive (lighting spark plugs, playing radio, etc). Then, when you go to start your car again, you don't have enough juice to start it up.

Most auto parts stores can hook up a tester to your battery and then test both the battery and the alternator. I would recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the battery is draining. Did you install any electronic gadgets other than that recommended and not part of factory kit?
When the engine is hot, the battery may not have enough charge to start the motor. Also, get the battery tested using a multimeter.

Comment: I'm not sure how this adds to the current answers... it would be great if you could [edit] to clarify that.  Also, given that the question is nearly 7 years old, it would probably be clearly indicate specific issues which could cause this problem, rather than requesting clarification from the OP.